# Scrolling Issues with mobile webpage

Tags: android, html, css, ios, mobile

I'm having Issue with Mobile scrolling. I can only scroll like 70% and then the webpage gets stuck. But on PC I can scroll all the way. Any Idea what might be causing this issue?

https://www.lovrirealestate.com/webbsida2/HTML/Projects.html